# Firebase database always returns null

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When reading from this firebase database it always returns null instead of the value I need.

I have tried pulling it in the form of a String with the String.class but its still null.

What I need to pull from the data base is just the int `dose` and the `pName` variable in this case would be `dfdf`

[image]

```
final FirebaseDatabase aDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
final DatabaseReference mDatabase = aDatabase.getReference();
DatabaseReference myRef =  aDatabase.getReference(pName).child("dose");

// Read from the database
myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
       // This method is called once with the initial value and again
       // whenever data at this location is updated.
       Integer Value = dataSnapshot.getValue(Integer.class);
       String peter = Integer.toString(Value);
       count.setText(peter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        count.setText("E");
    }
});
```

Comment: 1) Try using `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` instead 2) Log the value of the `dataSnapshot` or set a breakpoint in the debugger.

Comment: replace this `final FirebaseDatabase aDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();` to `final DatabaseReference aDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();`

Comment: addint the single  value event still returns null I am also changing this value with a button listener on the activity so I really don't want to have to use this method(I did try it though).

Comment: firebaseDatabases and DatabaseReference are two different types you are telling me to instantiate a Database reference and a firebaseDatabase the equivalent of String w1 = (Object) w2; doesn't work but a Reference can be a firebaseDatabase.reference();

Comment: It is an honor to have my name as a variable here :D

Comment: I did it In your honor lol actual I'm not the most professional variable namer

Comment: no it did not appear in the logcat @peter Haddad

Answer (score 2):

Try changing -

```
DatabaseReference myRef =  aDatabase.getReference(pName).child("dose");
```

to -

```
DatabaseReference myRef =  mDatabase.child(pName).child("dose");
```

you should be running on mDatabase not aDatabase and get the child not reference

And change the listener to

> addListenerForSingleValueEvent

Comment: mDatabase is another DatabaseReference that is less specific to be used in other parts of the code where I increment to dose aDatabase is the firebase database reference changing this will break the code

Comment: Ok, so to make this work, specifically, make another instance of it

Comment: good sir I thank you greatly you win all the cookies THIS IS THE CORRECT ANSWER !!! HORRAY

Comment: Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

```
DatabaseReference myRef = mDatabase.child(pName).child("dose");
```

Fix the reference as stated above.

Comment: mDatabase is another DatabaseReference that is less specific to be used in other parts of the code where I increment to dose aDatabase is the firebase database reference changing this will break the code even more

Comment: You might get another variable to get the reference of the node in your firebase database. However, the idea was to use `child()` in your reference.

Answer (score 0):

try this code ..

```
    private void readData(){
    final FirebaseDatabase aDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    final DatabaseReference mDatabase = aDatabase.getReference();

   // Read from the database child() method put your database name
    mDatabase.child("dfdf").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // This method is called once with the initial value and again
            // whenever data at this location is updated.
           // if i insert data as user class object then it give user.class
           // User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

            Integer Value = dataSnapshot.getValue(Integer.class);
            String peter = Integer.toString(Value);
            count.setText(peter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            count.setText("E");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: still comes back null

Comment: all the value given by Integer.class

Comment: What ever your pojo class inserted data it give only those class as read data time

Comment: Suppose all value define into User.class it return User.class

Comment: i think also check firebase database rule. if you want you can refer this link https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/firebase-realtime-database-crud/

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("dfdf");
myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
  int value = dataSnapshot.child("dose").getValue(Integer.class);
    Log.i("Value is:", value);
  }
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
    count.setText("E");
  }
});
```

The above will check if the snapshot `dfdf` exists then it enters the onDataChange and retrieves the child `dose`